# what is the function of HttpContext.Current.Request?

Tags: asp.net

1)When exactly we need to use HTTPContext (exclusively), please elaborate with an example if possible.

2)What does the following code do

```
internal string QueryString( string name ) 
{

    if ( HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[name] == null )
                return string.Empty;
            else {
                return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[name].ToString();
}
```

3)Is there any other alternative way where we avoid  using HttpContext

Comment: Refer to [HttpContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions here please

Answer (score -1):

Q1:

HttpContext is an object which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request. So, if you need to get any information about receiving HTTP request (for example in order to get the query string parameter values, referral urls, User's IP address etc), you need to use HttpContext object. Further more, this object contains information of current Request, Response, Server, Session, Cache, User and etc.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)

Usage and examples

1. Get current session Id: `HttpContext.Session.SessionID`
2. Get Timestamp of current request: `HttpContext.Timestamp.ToString()`

Q2:

In your code sample, you are trying get the value of query string parameter 'name'.

Your dummy request Url looks like - http://www.yourdomain.com/something?name=queryStringValue

- QueryString parameter = name
- QueryString parameter value = queryStringValue

Hope this helps.